# What error logs can I check to see why plugin updates are failing?

Tags: uploads, errors, permissions

I've updated to wordpress 4.7.x. I don't know why, but after doing so, I no longer have the ability to upload plugins (it keeps asking for FTP access. We've never used FTP always SFTP), and I can no longer update existing plugins. I get this error:

`Update Failed: Could not create directory.`

wp-config.php indeed was missing the `define(FS_METHOD, 'direct')` so I put it back. Still getting the error.

However, the apache error.log file contains no mention of an error. I feel like perhaps some permission issues got messed up somehow, but if that's the case, where on linux would I check to see a corresponding entry log for this error?

Answer (score 2):

In `wp-config.php`, set the following (if not already set):

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
@ini_set( 'display_errors', 0 );
```

This will make sure that on the site no error is shown, however, WordPress will log all errors in `debug.log` file inside the `/wp-content/` directory.

> NOTE: You must insert this BEFORE `/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */` in the `wp-config.php` file.

You'll find more details about it in this [Codex Document.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)

Answer (score 0):

If it's a WordPress, rather than an Apache error, you may not see anything on your server error logs. You can try enabling [WP_DEBUG](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) to see if anything shows up. That is generally my first step in debugging a WordPress site.

This [page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions#Permission_Scheme_for_WordPress) in the Codex provides a general permissions scheme. You can always check your file permissions via FTP (SFTP) or ssh.